# Props data to function object

Tags: reactjs, pdfmake

I want to put my props to text value in object content as text value. How I should do this?

Maybe is another one solutions for this? I also want to map to this object. For example name in names.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import pdfMake from "pdfmake/build/pdfmake";
import pdfFonts from "pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts";
pdfMake.vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;

class Print extends Component {
  printPdf(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    pdfMake
      .createPdf({
        content: [
          {
            text: "{this.props.order.name}",
            style: "header",
          },
        ],
        styles: {
          header: {
            fontSize: 18,
            bold: true,
          },
        },
      })
      .print();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Print">
        <button onClick={this.printPdf}>Print</button>
        {this.props.order.name}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Print;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want to be able to pass the printPdf function a prop, in addition to the event prop, the way to do that is at the onClick:

```
<button onClick={ (event) => { this.printPdf(event, this.props.order.name) } }>Print</button>
```

I added an anonymous arrow function, with which you then call your function and can pass it whatever you want.

And what you asked about the map- not really sure what you mean, but there is a for loop for object:

```
let obj = { key: val, key2: val2 };
for (let key in obj) { 
     console.log("key is ", key, "and the val is ", obj[key] );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your **second** question(**map**):

Assuming that props.order.name is an array:

```
{props.order.name.map((n, i) => ( <h1 key={i}>{ n.name}</h1> ))}
```

if props.order.name is an array is will be more proper to call it:

```
props.order.names
```

Then, the code would look like that:

```
{props.order.names.map((item, i) => ( <h1 key={i}>{ item.name}</h1> ))}
```

It just looks cleaner.